# Android Camera 2 API problems with flash on Nougat 7.1

Tags: android, flash, android-camera, android-7.0-nougat, android-camera2

Following the [Camera 2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample I've created simple camera class to capture the images. When it's okay with capturing both flash/non-flash images on any device with Android < 7.0, on mine Nexus 5X with Android 7.1 the same config fire the flash only once on the preview. Pre-sequences are the next:

- for the preview I'm using [CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#TEMPLATE_PREVIEW) with AE mode set to [CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH)
- the same I use for the capture still picture, but with [CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)

If someone can help me with this case - I'll be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**This is just additional information on the above issue. I wish to draw some attention to this problem!**

My application takes a photo every 5 seconds. I (1) select the camera, (2) acquirer a session and then with each loop I (3) create a Capture request in which I set the Flash Mode and call the capture method on the session.

I have no issues with my Samsung SM-G550T (Android version 6.01), but I was having some issues with the Flash Mode on my Moto G4 (Android version 7.0). I got both phones to Flash, but only with this setting:

```
CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
```

I am presently having an issue with a LG device (M210N) (Android version 7.0). Using the settings I stated above I get the device to flash just **once**. If I completely re-initialize the camera (as described above) the device will flash again only once.

If I add the `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH` setting to the above requestBuilder, then the LG does not flash at all. So I had to remove that flag.

**I have tried many different additional settings and combination for settings and none of them have eliminated this issue. I wonder how many devices are affected by this issue.**